# Proof of families of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

$M$ is set, and $C$ a colection non empty. And i want to prove that
$$M \cap \left(\bigcup_{A\in C} A\right)=\bigcup_{A\in C} (M \cap A)$$

$\Rightarrow$
Let $x$ be a element in $M \cap \left(\bigcup_{A\in C} A\right)$. By definition of intersection, we can say that $x\in M$ and $ x \in \bigcup_{A\in C} A$. We can concluide that $x\in A$, so $x \in C$. Thus $x \in \bigcup_{A \in C}(M \cap A)$

So $$M \cap \left(\bigcup_{A\in C} A\right) \subseteq \bigcup_{A\in C} (M \cap A)$$

Am I doing this right?

Comment: Looks good! Do the other inclusion for a complete proof.

Comment: Okay, i wasn't very sure if i was right. But now i'm going to to the other inclusion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is not quite correct: you say $x \in \bigcup_{A \in C} A$ implies $x \in A$ and $x \in C$. **No**, the correct conclusion is: there exists some $A \in C$ such that $x \in A$. Then (as $x \in M$ as well) for this same $A \in C$: $x \in M \cap A$, so by definition of the union, $x \in \bigcup_{A \in C} (M \cap A)$.

The reverse inclusion is similar, try it.